# translated enum fields in template tags

Tags: django, enums, django-templates, templatetags

I try to show the name of an enum in the template.To be clear,
I have enum like class in `model.py`

```
class EmployerWorkerNumberRange():
R_0 = 0
R_1_5 = 1
R_6_15 = 2
UNKNOWN = 3

EMPLOYER_WORKER_NUMBER_RANGE =(
    (R_0,_("wnr_0")),
    (R_1_5 ,_("wnr_1_5")),
    (R_6_15,_("wnr_6_15")),
    (UNKNOWN,_("UnknownWorkerNumberRange")),
)
```

When I use it in form like

`wnr = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("emp_full_reg_wnr"), required=True, choices=EmployerWorkerNumberRange.EMPLOYER_WORKER_NUMBER_RANGE)`

it works great.(Fills the dropdown with translated values and when I get the selected item it turns just the id)

My question is how can I show any translated value in my template by giving the id of it.
For example, I would like to use it `EmployerWorkerNumberRange.EMPLOYER_WORKER_NUMBER_RANGE[0]`

Could you suggest me any way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To show human-readable from of field value, use `get_$var_display()` method (created automatically for all fields with `choices`) on model instance.  For your example it's something like this:

```
{{ company.get_wnr_display }}
```

To get value by index without model instance, the easiest way is write custom filter that will convert index stored in a variable to needed value:

```
{{ some_value|as_wnr_title }}
```

Comment: It works perfect,thanks! Is there any document that I can read about such things? I have read the django documentations but I haven't noticed such usage..

Comment: It's all in django documentation, you might've been looking at wrong sections.  This particular method is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/